# как записать SQL запрос чтобы получить кортеж из двух значений одной таблицы и связанного значения другой?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

есть две таблицы в бд SQLite3 для работы приложения на Python..\

```
CREATE TABLE product_table (
 -------------id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 -------------product_name VARCHAR,
 -------------product_type_id INTEGER
 -------------price INTEGER,
 -------------product_photo_id INTEGER,
 -------------PRIMARY KEY (id),
 -------------FOREIGH KEY(product_type_id) REFERENCES product_types (id),
 -------------FOREIGN KEY(product_photo_id) REFERENSES product_photos (id),                      
)

CREATE TABLE product_photos (
 -------------id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 -------------product_id INTEGER,
 -------------telegram_photo_id VARCHAR
 -------------PRIMARY KEY (id),
 -------------FOREIGH KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product_table (id),                 
)

# Третья для полной картины
CREATE TABLE product_types (
 -------------id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 -------------product_type VARCHAR
 -------------PRIMARY KEY (id),                     
)
# Таблицы заполнял через БД браузер вручную, потому что так на тот момент было удобнее..но мог бы и так
conn.execute('INSERT into product_table (product_name, product_type_id, price, product_photo_id) VALUES ("кот", 20, 1, 1)')

conn.execute('INSERT into product_photos (product_id, telegram_photo_id) VALUES (1, "file_id от телергамм")')
conn.commit()
```

**Требуемый вывод [('Кот','20','*file_id от телергамм*')]**

Как вывести первые два - тут все просто ***execute(f'SELECT product_name, price, product_photo_id FROM product_table WHERE product_type_id={cat_code}').fetchall()***
Не понятно именно как добавить в выходной кортеж значение из другой таблицы по связанному полю,
Пробую написать через JOIN, но не понимаю как указать **WHERE product_type_id==*знач***, а мне нужно именно по типу "отбирать", который приходит в функцию в качестве **cat_code** и равен одному из *product_types.id* поэтому использую *fstring*.

Нужно решение именно в виде SQL запроса, без alchemy и тд, потому что хочу понять именно сам SQL

Comment: *Поле product_photo_id связано с полем id в product_photos, product_id связано с id из product_table* Это как? перекрёстная ссылка? А если продукт ссылается на фото, которое ссылается на другой продукт? Дайте лучше структуры не картинками, а в форме их CREATE TABLE, включая и внешние ключи.

Comment: *Нужно решение именно в виде SQL запроса* Добавьте к структурам в формате CREATE TABLE ещё и пример данных в формате INSERT INTO и требуемый результат на этих данных, с пояснениями, почему именно так.

Comment: обновил вопрос с CREATE форматом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT pt.product_name, 
       pt.product_type_id,
       pp.telegram_photo_id
FROM product_table pt
-- Из следующих двух строк - одну выбрать, вторую удалить.
-- Какую выбрать - зависит от логики предметной области.
-- Впрочем, допускаю, что правильным может оказаться третий вариант.
JOIN product_photos pp ON pt.product_photo_id = pp.id
JOIN product_photos pp  ON pp.product_id = pt.id
```

Comment: Супер, только в моем случае получается нужно:
```sql
SELECT pt.product_name, 
                pt.price, 
                pp.telegram_photo_id
FROM product_table pt 
JOIN product_photos pp 
ON pt.product_photo_id = pp.id 
WHERE pt.product_type_id = 2

Огромное спасибо, вроде как разобрался!